# ffmpeg library for convert and compress video

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg library for convert and compress video.but not getting the best result with minimum size but not satisfied with the result.
What is the best way to compress video with ffmpeg library with provided options?
can anybody give me the best options to use for that?

Comment: If there were one set of best parameters to fit all use cases, these would be hardcoded into ffmpeg in the first place. You should read how Netflix addressed this challenge recently.

Answer (score -1):

Video conversion and compression mainly depends on five factors i.e. fps/video bitrate/audio sample rate/profile/Constant Rate Factor. Try manipulating these three factors, at one specification you will definitely get the best result.

```
ffpmpeg -i <input_file> -y -strict experimental -acodec copy -ab *<audio bitrate>* -ac 2 -ar 48000 -vcodec copy -vprofile *<profile you want i.e. either baseline or main>* -level 30 -g 48 -b *<video_bitrate>* -crf *<within 18-24>* -r *<frame_rate/fps>* <output_file>
```

Comment: You can't steam copy and use encoding options at the same time.

Comment: in the command am only copying the codec of the original video and specification am providing manually. So, if my original video's vcodec is libx264, the output video will have same vcodec but bitrate/fps will be the one i have provided

Comment: No. `-vcodec copy` means to relay input video packets to the output unaltered, except for some stuff like timestamps..etc